# python matplotlib correcting X and Y of np.meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a function with 2 variables to a 2D plain. I also want some trial points in it. However, the result I get is not what I want. The X and Y values range from 0 to 40 (I wanted them to be between -1.5 and 2) and completely mismatch the function's actual values (with x = 15 and y = 15 it is definitely not 0).

[image: The result I got]

However, the color map and the contour lines with numbers seem correct when I compare this to a top-down view of a 3D plot (it actually is between -1.5 and 2)

[image: Comparisson of the 2D plot on the left and top-down view of the 3D plot (the X and Y values are correct on it)]

Lastly, the trail points (red dots in the first picture) are plotted according to the wrong X and Y values and are in the wrong place. How do I fix these problems? I am quite new to Numpy and matplotlib and I am guessing, that I used either np.arange or np.meshgrid wrong. I would like to either have a 2D image with the correct X and Y axis and trial points or a 3D plot with at least trial points that are always visible( the way I tried it, they seemed to be drawn before the 3D plot and would not be visible most of the time, having contour lines would be perfect). There is code I use to do calculations and plotting

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    return -( x * y * (1 - x - y) ) / 8

def partial_x_der(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    return (-y * (-2 * x - y + 1)) / 8

def partial_y_der(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    return (-x * (1 - x - 2 * y) ) / 8

def gradient(x: float, y: float):
    return (partial_x_der(x, y), partial_y_der(x, y))

def tuple_minus(my_tuple1: tuple, my_tuple2: tuple) -> tuple:
    return (my_tuple1[0] - my_tuple2[0], my_tuple1[1] - my_tuple2[1])

def tuple_multi_val(my_tuple: tuple, value: float) -> tuple:
    return (my_tuple[0] * value, my_tuple[1] * value)

def gradiant_descent(start_point: tuple, learning_rate: float, epsilon: float) -> list:
    max_iterations = 1000
    cur_point = start_point
    result_points = list()
    for iter in range(max_iterations):
        next_point = tuple_multi_val(gradient(cur_point[0], cur_point[1]), learning_rate)
        if np.abs(next_point[0]) < epsilon and np.abs(next_point[1]) < epsilon:
            print(f"With learning rate {learning_rate} minimum found at ({cur_point[0] - next_point[0]};{cur_point[1] - next_point[1]}) with value of {func(cur_point[0], cur_point[1])}, iterations needed: {iter}")
            result_points.append((cur_point[0], cur_point[1], func(cur_point[0], cur_point[1])))
            return result_points
        cur_point = tuple_minus(cur_point, next_point)
        if iter % 10 == 0:
            result_points.append((cur_point[0], cur_point[1], func(cur_point[0], cur_point[1])))

    print(f"Max iteraration count of {max_iterations} reached, Minimum value found at ({cur_point[0]};{cur_point[1]}) ")
    result_points.append((cur_point[0], cur_point[1], func(cur_point[0], cur_point[1])))
    return result_points

def show_gradient_descend(points_to_show: list):
    x = np.arange(-1.5,2,0.1)
    y = np.arange(-1.5,2,0.1)
    X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = func(X, Y)
    
    # 2D plot
    im = plt.imshow(Z, 'GnBu', origin='lower') # drawing the function
    # adding the Contour lines with labels
    plt.cset = plt.contour(Z, np.arange(-0.5, 1, 0.1), linewidths=1, cmap=plt.cm.Set2)
    plt.clabel(plt.cset, inline=True, fmt='%1.1f', fontsize=8)
    plt.colorbar(im) # adding the colobar on the right
    for point in points_to_show:
        plt.scatter(point[0], point[1], color='r', marker='o')
    
    # 3D plot
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap='GnBu',linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    # title
    plt.title('$z= -(x*y*(1-x-y)) / 8$')
    plt.xlabel("X")
    plt.ylabel("Y")
    plt.show()

def main():
    x0 = (0, 0)
    x1 = (1, 1)
    xm = (5/10, 9/10)
    epsilon = 0.0001
    points = [x0, x1, xm]
    #for learning_rate in np.linspace(0,1,101):
    #  gradiant_descent(xm, learning_rate, epsilon)
    for point in points:
        points_to_show = gradiant_descent(point, 0.42, 0.0001)

    show_gradient_descend(points_to_show)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks for any advice or help in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the `extent` parameter of [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).  There is an [example of its use in the matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_image.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contour-image-py).

Comment: In addition to specifying the extent, also add X and Y for the contourplot (`plt.contour(X, Y, Z, ...`), otherwise Matplotlib has no way of knowing what coordinates you are using.

Comment: Thank you @WarrenWeckesser, I managed to fix it and made it how I wanted :))